# can not resolve the symbol AppcomapatActivity

Tags: java, android

I am just starting to learn android and i just installed android studio on windows 10 pc. And the very first problem that I am facing is "can not resolve the symbol "AppCompatActivity". Here is my gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "quikkhome.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

      dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is problem

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

you are added 2 time

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

remove one time may be its help you

Comment: i copied it twice by mistake. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem (though I do not know how did it work). I just changed the API from 21 to 23 and then back to 21. It is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at your xml layout files, make sure all are targeting the same API.  Change them to what ever you are targeting if different, like API 23 for example.  The latest API may not be working yet, like N preview for example. This can be done by clicking the 'design' tab at the bottom if you are looking at an xml layout.  Look for the little android man with the number beside it, click it.

Now also make sure the same theme is selected for all layout files.  For example you may be using AppTheme as the theme.

Last run 'clean project'.  At the top click Build, in the drop down menu click Clean Project.